# How to calibrate a qubit other than qubit 0?

Tags: qiskit, openpulse

I replicated successfully the qiskit tutorial (in a jupyter notebook using VSCode) found here: https://learn.qiskit.org/course/quantum-hardware-pulses/calibrating-qubits-using-qiskit-pulse

But when I tried to calibrate a different qubit (changing the line `qubit = 0` to, say, `qubit = 1`, I get only background noise (ranging from -6.15 to -5.90 a.u.) instead of a nice peak (reaching around 2 a.u.) when plotting `sweep_values`. By the way, I don't know if this is important, I had to also change the line `sweep_values.append(res[qubit])` to `sweep_values.append(res[0])` because it was giving me an error (`res` is of size 1). This was on ibm_hanoi.

Why do I get only noise when switching to another qubit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you modify this cell in section 2?

```
sweep_gate = Gate("sweep", 1, [freq])

qc_sweep = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)

qc_sweep.append(sweep_gate, [0])
qc_sweep.measure(0, 0)
qc_sweep.add_calibration(sweep_gate, (0,), sweep_sched, [freq])

# Create the frequency settings for the sweep (MUST BE IN HZ)
frequencies_Hz = frequencies_GHz*GHz
exp_sweep_circs = [qc_sweep.assign_parameters({freq: f}, inplace=False) for f in frequencies_Hz]
```

Try replacing it with this:

```
n_bits = backend_config.n_qubits
sweep_gate = Gate("sweep", 1, [freq])

qc_sweep = QuantumCircuit(n_bits, 1)

qc_sweep.append(sweep_gate, [qubit])
qc_sweep.measure(qubit, 0)
qc_sweep.add_calibration(sweep_gate, (qubit,), sweep_sched, [freq])

# Create the frequency settings for the sweep (MUST BE IN HZ)
frequencies_Hz = frequencies_GHz*GHz
exp_sweep_circs = [qc_sweep.assign_parameters({freq: f}, inplace=False) for f in frequencies_Hz]
```

I would recommend looking through all the cells to see if there are other places where they also assumed qubit = 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll check later when I have time and report back.

Comment: That worked just fine, thanks a lot! They should change the tutorial, I think, as it gives the impression that all you have to do is change the line `qubit = 0`.